# NightmareJS : "Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#LINK1$1' is not a valid selector."

Tags: javascript, nightmare

I'm using NightmareJS to scrape a website for data, and that site uses id's on they're anchor tags in similar fashion to the code below.

```
<div>
    <a id="#LINK1$1"></a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use the '.click(Selector)' method, which uses querySelector as a default, but I can't seem to get the anchor tag by id.
I've tried both

```
.click('#LINK1$1'),
.click('\u{0023}LINK\u{0031}\u{0024}\u{0031}')
```

But they both result in the same error

```
"Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#LINK1$1' is not a valid selector."
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Xpath way to do this. Puppeteer has an xpath function.

## Theory

From their docs,

```
page.$x(expression)
expression <string> Expression to evaluate.
returns: <Promise<Array<ElementHandle>>>
The method evaluates the XPath expression.
```

It will return an array of elements. We can `click` them as we want.

## Practice

Get the xpath for element,
[image]

Now apply it,

```
// we execute the xpath
const elems = await page.$x(`//*[@id="#LINK1$1"]`)

// We click the first element, since it returns an array
await elems[0].click();
```

Done!

btw this also works on browser,

```
function getElementByXpath(path) {
  return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}
getElementByXpath(`//*[@id="#LINK1$1"]`)
// >> Returns single node <a id=​"#LINK1$1">​Test​</a>​
```